# Environment Hub orgs not appearing in list of hub members

Tags: environment-hub, trialforce

I am trying to spin orgs using environment hub. I can successfully spin an org; however, the org does not save in my hub members.

I am not using a domain, anyone have any quick solutions as to why I wouldn't see the org in my list after I create an org?

Thanks

Comment: How long did you wait before checking? did you refresh? It takes a little while for them to show up

Comment: I waited a few hours and I refreshed a million times. Checked again this morning and it is still not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I logged a case with Saleforce support and they are getting the R&D team on it. If this happens, contact Salesforce support for help.

In the meantime, you can manually connect your orgs by deploying a domain to all users and save the all org information manually. I have been having some issues getting this to work, but I hear it works.